# Mysql: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql

I earlier made a database in mysql and now i am trying to list all the values from it in a table, but I get the following error `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean` on line: `while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))`

Here is my code:

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) {
    die("Error: " . mysql_error);
}

mysql_select_db("my_db",$con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Email adress</th>
</tr>";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['emailadress'] . "</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
```

I read other similar question but diden't get an answer.

Comment: You should dump the variable `$result`. If I guess right then failes the sql statment. I just don't know the cause.

Comment: i am verry new at mysql. what exacly can I do?

Comment: Write for debugging a `var_dump($result)` into your code right after the `mysql_query` line. By the way if you are new to mysql use better PDO that is much safer then the old `mysql_` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't evaluate the response from MySQL about selecting the database or running your query. The error indicates that your query didn't succeed (hence mysql_query returns FALSE) - which means one or both of the above didn't work.

Test for errors when you select the database and use die(mysql_error()); to see why these calls are failing.

Comment: i have no error at selecting the database. what ealse can I try?

Comment: I did this:
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users");
    
    if (!result)
    {
     die(mysql_error());
    }

and got this error: `Notice: Use of undefined constant result - assumed 'result'`

Comment: You have a typo. PHP variables always begin with $.

Comment: Can someone tell me how do I use in file b.php the database I created in file a.php? I connected and selected the database succesfully but I can't use the TABLE I made in file a.php. Why?

Comment: Separate question somewhat. But remember MySQL is case sensitive - Users, users and USERS are three different tables. Provided you're connecting to the same server, selecting the same database, and choosing the same table, it doesn't matter what file you're in. MySQL data is separate from your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this line is actually getting the rows from the table:
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users");

Try doing an error check in that query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users") or die(mysql_error());
```

Possibly your table is called "users" and not "Users" (note the caps), so change accordingly.

Regards,
Richi