# mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get data from the database but experiencing this error. There is no error in the query as it runs perfectly in mysql.

Why i am getting this error then ?

```
[client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/imdb.php on line 35

[client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/imdb.php on line 35
```

php code:

```
    function getdirector($director)
    {
    global $db;
    $query = 'select name from peopledb where peopleid = '.$director;
    $result = mysql_query($query,$db) or die(mysql_error($db));
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    extract($row);
    return $name;
    }

    function getactor($actor)
    {
    $query = 'select name from peopledb where peopleid = '.$actor;
    $result = mysql_query($query,$db) or die(mysql_error($db));
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    extract($row);
    return $name;
    }


    function getmovietype($type)
    {
    $query = 'select movietype from movietype where movieid = '.$type;
    $result = mysql_query($query,$db) or die(mysql_error($db));
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    extract($row);
    return $movietype;
    }

    $db = mysql_connect('localhost','root','saw123') or die("Connection error");
    $db = mysql_select_db("moviesite",$db) or die(myql_error($db));
    $query = 'select moviename,releaseyear,director,actor,type from movie';
    $result = mysql_query($query,$db) or die(mysql_error($db));

    $table = <<<ENDHTML
    <div style="text-align: center;" >
    <h2>The Ultimate movie database</h2>
    <table border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='2'
           style="width: 70%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">

    <tr>
    <th>Movie title</th>
    <th>year of release </th>
    <th>Movie director</th>
    <th>Movie Actor</th>
    <th>Movie type</th>
    </tr>
    ENDHTML;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    extract($row);
    $director1 = getdirector($director);
    $actor1 = getactor($actor);
    $movietype1 = getmovietype($type);

    $table .= <<<ENDHTML
    <tr>
    <td>$moviename</td>
    <td>$releaseyear</td>
    <td>$director1</td>
    <td>$actor1</td>
    <td>$movietype1</td>
    </tr>
    ENDHTML;
    }
    $table .=<<<ENDHTML
    </table>
    </div>
    ENDHTML;

    echo $table;


    ?>
```

***UPDATE :::   it was showing error wherever i was using mysql_error() function. Now after removing all the "$db" parameters, it just works. Why ?***

Comment: My daily rant: This question comes along several times a day on SO, and unfortunately, today is not an exception.

Comment: I even missed the one 4 minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108322/mysql-warning-mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource

Comment: With regards to your update, I explained why in my answer: The $db = mysql_select_db("moviesite",$db) or die(myql_error($db));  line sets $db to either true or false - since mysql_select_db only ever returns a boolean.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the 
community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See
 the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared
 statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://in3.php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you.
 If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO).
 Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: @user1263375 did it end up working for you?

Comment: @JvdBerg I didn't realize it was that widespread... you may be on to something :P http://i.minus.com/ibcEqNJOAKRxxt.png (this is just the list of related questions to the side of this question).

Answer (score 1):

Just call it this way:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

If you look at the mysql_connect function it returns false  ( a boolean) on failure:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

So your connection is likely not even established.

Edit: Look at this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

You're calling:

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','root','saw123') or die("Connection error");
    $db = mysql_select_db("moviesite",$db) or die(myql_error($db));
```

The second line sets $db to either true or false - since mysql_select_db only ever returns a boolean.

Edit 2:
What you likely meant was:

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','root','saw123') or die("Connection error");
mysql_select_db("moviesite",$db) or die(myql_error($db));
```

$db in this case would not be appropriately named; it'd be more accurately called $connection or $db_connection or something like that.

Comment: and do no error checking at all? How is he going to debug his queries then?

Comment: +1 however, the error checking with regards to a connection should happen at the beginning when the DB connection is established.  The second parameter is only required if he has multiple DB connections.

Comment: ajacian - true, but there also needs to be error checking *after every query*.

Comment: @user1263375 check my edit, I didn't see your second $db = line. That's your problem.

Comment: Ahh, I misjudged the problem. You're right, `$db` is out of scope and that is the issue

Comment: It's not out of scope, you're using it incorrectly. I will edit to show you what I mean.

Comment: @Pekka correct, however when there's only one connection to the DB in a script, adding it to the mysql_query call doesn't help in error checking if he checks for connection status when he establishes a connection.  I could be wrong and if there's documentation otherwise, I'd like to see it :). Either way, OP should be using mysqli  -- too many PHP tutorials still show mysql based examples.